# Different character types of same column into date format

Tags: r

I have an excel file with columns Date_of_visit & As_of_date and 2 rows. While I'm loading into data frame one row is in date format and another in numeric. I want to format the column into same format.

I'm trying the below code with no luck

```
    df$Date_of_visit <- as.Date(as.numeric(df$Date_of_visit), origin = "1899-12-30")
    df$As_of_date <- as.Date(as.numeric(df$As_of_date), origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Output I got:

[image]

I tried different methods, but could not succeeded.
Hope anyone of you can help me.

Comment: could you share `dput(df)`?

Comment: What does Shiny have to do with your question?

Comment: This post might be helpful/related ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60254796/conditional-conversion-from-character-to-date-for-a-dataframe-column-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

An option is to create an index for the `NA` elements when converting to `numeric`

```
v1 <- as.numeric(df$Date_of_visit)
df$As_of_date <- as.Date(rep(NA, nrow(df)))
df$As_of_date[is.na(v1)] <- as.Date(df$Date_of_visit[is.na(v1)], "%d/%m/%Y")
df$As_of_date[!is.na(v1)] <- as.Date(v1[!is.na(v1)], origin = "1899-12-30")
```